# Stack View & Content Hugging Priority - Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I have inside a collection view cell a stack view with 3 elements (2 image views and 1 label), as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]
What I'm trying to achieve, is to have the label taking all the possible empty space instead of image views, which is what is shown in the xib.
In theory, the following goal should be achieved simply having a bigger `Content Hugging Priority` value on the image views, since a high value implies that we don’t want that a certain view to be larger then its content.

But the curious results that I get from various experiments are the following:

## 1 Not working as expected

Content hugging on ImageViews: 251

Content hugging on Label: 250

[image]

## 2 OK

Content hugging on ImageViews: 999

Content hugging on Label: 250

[image]

So, even if both cases should be working theoretically at the same way, (as in the interface builder) the truth is that at runtime they aren't! Do you know why is this happening? What did I miss? Thanks!

PS: The stack view has `Distribution: fill` and center alignment

Answer (score 0):

Set a width & height constraints for the 2 images

[image]

Also don't forget to implement `sizeForItemAt`

Comment: Yes thanks, I know of course that I can put constraints and solve it in that way (which is less maintainable then the solution #2 I posted), but that's not the point of my question